# How can I find and edit the input classes reported by "xinput list --long"

Tags: linux-mint, xorg, xinput

I found these configurations and "classes" using the xinput utility on Linux Mint. Hours of documentation-crawling and googling yielded no information about them. Can anyone tell me what they are, where to find them, and if it is possible to edit them?

I ask because I recently installed Linux Mint Mate (17.2) on my laptop and the touchpad is incorrectly configured. It works like a touchscreen, zipping the cursor to a new location whenever I touch it. My hours of googling hinted that in the lines I printed below, its mode should be "dependant" instead of "direct".

Thanks, here's the stuff I found:

```
xinput list --long
```

prints the following:

```
⎡ Virtual core pointer                      id=2    [master pointer  (3)]
Reporting 9 classes:
    Class originated from: 11. Type: XIButtonClass
    Buttons supported: 16
    Button labels: "Button Unknown" "Button Unknown" "Button Unknown" "Button Wheel Up" "Button Wheel Down" "Button Horiz Wheel Left" "Button Horiz Wheel Right" None None None None None None None None None
    Button state:
    Class originated from: 11. Type: XIValuatorClass
    Detail for Valuator 0:
      Label: Abs MT Position X
      Range: 0.000000 - 3312.000000
      Resolution: 10000 units/m
      Mode: absolute
      Current value: 1369.000000
    Class originated from: 11. Type: XIValuatorClass
    Detail for Valuator 1:
      Label: Abs MT Position Y
      Range: 0.000000 - 1872.000000
      Resolution: 10000 units/m
      Mode: absolute
      Current value: 1872.000000
    Class originated from: 11. Type: XIValuatorClass
    Detail for Valuator 2:
      Label: Abs MT Touch Major
      Range: 0.000000 - 255.000000
      Resolution: 1000 units/m
      Mode: absolute
      Current value: 2.000000
    Class originated from: 11. Type: XIValuatorClass
    Detail for Valuator 3:
      Label: Abs MT Touch Minor
      Range: 0.000000 - 255.000000
      Resolution: 1000 units/m
      Mode: absolute
      Current value: 1.000000
    Class originated from: 11. Type: XIValuatorClass
    Detail for Valuator 4:
      Label: Abs MT Orientation
      Range: 0.000000 - 1.000000
      Resolution: 0 units/m
      Mode: absolute
      Current value: 1.000000
    Class originated from: 11. Type: XIValuatorClass
    Detail for Valuator 5:
      Label: Abs MT Tool X
      Range: 0.000000 - 3312.000000
      Resolution: 10000 units/m
      Mode: absolute
      Current value: 1369.000000
    Class originated from: 11. Type: XIValuatorClass
    Detail for Valuator 6:
      Label: Abs MT Tool Y
      Range: 0.000000 - 1872.000000
      Resolution: 10000 units/m
      Mode: absolute
      Current value: 1872.000000
    Class originated from: 11. Type: XITouchClass
    Touch mode: direct
    Max number of touches: 5
⎜   ↳ Virtual core XTEST pointer                id=4    [slave  pointer  (2)]
    Reporting 3 classes:
        Class originated from: 4. Type: XIButtonClass
        Buttons supported: 10
        Button labels: "Button Left" "Button Middle" "Button Right" "Button Wheel Up" "Button Wheel Down" "Button Horiz Wheel Left" "Button Horiz Wheel Right" None None None
        Button state:
        Class originated from: 4. Type: XIValuatorClass
        Detail for Valuator 0:
          Label: Rel X
          Range: -1.000000 - -1.000000
          Resolution: 0 units/m
          Mode: relative
        Class originated from: 4. Type: XIValuatorClass
        Detail for Valuator 1:
          Label: Rel Y
          Range: -1.000000 - -1.000000
          Resolution: 0 units/m
          Mode: relative

⎜   ↳ ETPS/2 Elantech Touchpad                  id=14   [slave  pointer  (2)]
    Reporting 10 classes:
        Class originated from: 14. Type: XIButtonClass
        Buttons supported: 12
        Button labels: "Button Left" "Button Middle" "Button Right" "Button Wheel Up" "Button Wheel Down" "Button Horiz Wheel Left" "Button Horiz Wheel Right" None None None None None
        Button state:
        Class originated from: 14. Type: XIValuatorClass
        Detail for Valuator 0:
          Label: Rel X
          Range: 0.000000 - 3249.000000
          Resolution: 33000 units/m
          Mode: relative
        Class originated from: 14. Type: XIValuatorClass
        Detail for Valuator 1:
          Label: Rel Y
          Range: 0.000000 - 2223.000000
          Resolution: 33000 units/m
          Mode: relative
        Class originated from: 14. Type: XIValuatorClass
        Detail for Valuator 2:
          Label: Rel Horiz Scroll
          Range: 0.000000 - -1.000000
          Resolution: 0 units/m
          Mode: relative
        Class originated from: 14. Type: XIValuatorClass
        Detail for Valuator 3:
          Label: Rel Vert Scroll
          Range: 0.000000 - -1.000000
          Resolution: 0 units/m
          Mode: relative
        Class originated from: 14. Type: XIValuatorClass
        Detail for Valuator 4:
          Label: Abs MT Touch Major
          Range: 0.000000 - 2565.000000
          Resolution: 0 units/m
          Mode: absolute
          Current value: 0.000000
        Class originated from: 14. Type: XIValuatorClass
        Detail for Valuator 5:
          Label: Abs MT Pressure
          Range: 0.000000 - 255.000000
          Resolution: 0 units/m
          Mode: absolute
          Current value: 0.000000
        Class originated from: 14. Type: XIScrollClass
        Scroll info for Valuator 2
          type: 2 (horizontal)
          increment: 78.000000
          flags: 0x0
        Class originated from: 14. Type: XIScrollClass
        Scroll info for Valuator 3
          type: 1 (vertical)
          increment: 78.000000
          flags: 0x0
        Class originated from: 14. Type: XITouchClass
        Touch mode: direct
        Max number of touches: 5

⎜   ↳ 2.4G Wireless Wireless Receiver           id=9    [slave  pointer  (2)]
    Reporting 7 classes:
        Class originated from: 9. Type: XIButtonClass
        Buttons supported: 16
        Button labels: "Button Left" "Button Middle" "Button Right" "Button Wheel Up" "Button Wheel Down" "Button Horiz Wheel Left" "Button Horiz Wheel Right" "Button Side" "Button Extra" "Button Forward" "Button Back" "Button Task" "Button Unknown" "Button Unknown" "Button Unknown" "Button Unknown"
        Button state:
        Class originated from: 9. Type: XIValuatorClass
        Detail for Valuator 0:
          Label: Rel X
          Range: -1.000000 - -1.000000
          Resolution: 1 units/m
          Mode: relative
        Class originated from: 9. Type: XIValuatorClass
        Detail for Valuator 1:
          Label: Rel Y
          Range: -1.000000 - -1.000000
          Resolution: 1 units/m
          Mode: relative
        Class originated from: 9. Type: XIValuatorClass
        Detail for Valuator 2:
          Label: Rel Horiz Wheel
          Range: -1.000000 - -1.000000
          Resolution: 1 units/m
          Mode: relative
        Class originated from: 9. Type: XIValuatorClass
        Detail for Valuator 3:
          Label: Rel Vert Wheel
          Range: -1.000000 - -1.000000
          Resolution: 1 units/m
          Mode: relative
        Class originated from: 9. Type: XIScrollClass
        Scroll info for Valuator 2
          type: 2 (horizontal)
          increment: 1.000000
          flags: 0x0
        Class originated from: 9. Type: XIScrollClass
        Scroll info for Valuator 3
          type: 1 (vertical)
          increment: -1.000000
          flags: 0x2 ( preferred )

⎣ Virtual core keyboard                     id=3    [master keyboard (2)]
    Reporting 1 classes:
        Class originated from: 13. Type: XIKeyClass
        Keycodes supported: 248

    ↳ Virtual core XTEST keyboard               id=5    [slave  keyboard (3)]
    Reporting 1 classes:
        Class originated from: 5. Type: XIKeyClass
        Keycodes supported: 248

    ↳ Power Button                              id=6    [slave  keyboard (3)]
    Reporting 1 classes:
        Class originated from: 6. Type: XIKeyClass
        Keycodes supported: 248

    ↳ Video Bus                                 id=7    [slave  keyboard (3)]
    Reporting 1 classes:
        Class originated from: 7. Type: XIKeyClass
        Keycodes supported: 248

    ↳ Sleep Button                              id=8    [slave  keyboard (3)]
    Reporting 1 classes:
        Class originated from: 8. Type: XIKeyClass
        Keycodes supported: 248

    ↳ USB2.0 UVC HD Webcam                      id=10   [slave  keyboard (3)]
    Reporting 1 classes:
        Class originated from: 10. Type: XIKeyClass
        Keycodes supported: 248

    ↳ Asus WMI hotkeys                          id=12   [slave  keyboard (3)]
    Reporting 1 classes:
        Class originated from: 12. Type: XIKeyClass
        Keycodes supported: 248

    ↳ AT Translated Set 2 keyboard              id=13   [slave  keyboard (3)]
    Reporting 1 classes:
        Class originated from: 13. Type: XIKeyClass
        Keycodes supported: 248
```

Answer (score 0):

Set mode should work: `--set-mode device RELATIVE`